# Linear Regression with independent variables using scikit python

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, scikit-learn

I am new to Scikit-Learn and I need to solve the problem about predicting new data using Python. 
I have a 2 dimensional datatable as below: (Sorry I can't create 2 dimension table here) 
-----------------------------------------------------
Date -----|                            Hour
-----------------------------------------------------
------------| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |.....| 23 |
01 - Jan | 3 | 7 | 22 | 46 | .... | 94 | 
...
23 - Sep | x | x | x | x |... 
My table has 1 dimension is Date, and one other is Hour. Each day will have 24 hour. Each hour will get a random 2-digit number which is independent with others. Now can I predict new data for the next days using Linear Regression? Please help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if i understand your question correctly, for each hour on a date, you get a random 2 digit number. You have a set of dates with corresponding random 2-digit numbers and now for a new date where you dont have the random 2-digit numbers from, you want a linear regression to predict what that 2-digit number is.

However, i do not know if that is the best solution. With a Linear Regression you want a predictor (Date/Hour) and use that to predict a parameter/value (2-digit number). You mention though, that the value is random, and that would mean that there is no relation. Unless there is one that you didn't mention, i don't think you can predict what the 2-digit number is going to be. At best you can just predict new 2-digit numbers by generating a new random 2-digit number.

If you still want to do a [Linear Regression with Scikit-Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html), you need to split your data into a training and a test set, and into an X and an y.
Your Training set is the dates and hours(y) and numbers (x) you know, your test set is the date and hour(y). Mind you, that you want to combine the Date and hour into 1 record, so you get instances as: 23-Sept-01, 23-Sept-02, .., 23-Sept-23. (where is your 24th hour?)
I would also suggest to split your data before you load it into python, or split it using [numpy matrices](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html). You can use the predict function to predict your 2-digit numbers in that way using Linear Regression.

Hope this helps, sorry for the formatting if it is messy (new here)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case, the new number is generated randomly, without any dependence to data/time or previous numbers and it's hardly to predict. But can "history always repeats itself" in this case? If I consider Date&Time as (y), and numbers as (x), based on a large old data, still have a good prediction with Linear Regression?

Comment: @James Do: I don't think it can. Linear Regression is a prediction technique as you said, but it can only predict something if there is a relationship between the (Numbers)X and (Date&Time)Y. As you said: "the new number is generated randomly, without any dependence to data/time or previous numbers" means there is no relationship between the numbers. The generation of the number is not affected by the Date or the Time, so the Linear Regression can't find any pattern. And therefor it cannot predict what the number is, since you might as well put a random number there.